# Db2 on Cloud: How to upload a CSV?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I have an IBM Cloud account and provisioned Db2 on Cloud with the lite plan. I'm facing some issues in uploading a CSV File.

Based on the course instruction we should be able to upload the CSV file under the column manage and Click the button "open the console" and load the CSV. I am unable to locate the button "open the console".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In many cloud environments, services and their features change more often than in on-premises products. For Db2 on Cloud, the button "Open Console" seems to be the "Go to UI" now. That should bring up the management console / UI. Expect that the UI has changed there, too. I recommend reading the [FAQ for the Db2 lite plan and information about the ongoing migration](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-faq_lite).